# Android - How do I implement Facebook Share properly?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I've spent my entire morning trying to implement a Facebook share button to my application and I don't quite get it to work.

I've tried to follow this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

The "getActivity()" (5 of them, in onComplete) methods give the error "Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()' and I'm lost at what to do right now. I've tried tagging everything that has to do with the Facebook share to make it easier to read here. I may add that everything was working perfectly before adding the share function. I may have put the code in the wrong places or misunderstood the guide so any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Results.java

```
package com.example.xxx.zzz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//START: FACEBOOK - SHARE
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
//END: FACEBOOK - SHARE

public class Results extends FragmentActivity {

    //START: FACEBOOK - SHARE
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    //END: FACEBOOK - SHARE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //START: FACEBOOK - SHARE
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //END: FACEBOOK - SHARE

        themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        Bundle BMIData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (BMIData == null) {
            return;
        }

        String BMIMessage = BMIData.getString("BMIMessage");
        String BMIText = BMIData.getString("BMIText");
        final TextView ResultBMITextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultBMITextView);
        final TextView ResultBMITextTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResultBMITextTextView);
        ResultBMITextView.setText(BMIMessage);
        ResultBMITextTextView.setText(BMIText);
    }

    public void onClickResultsBack(View view) {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i1);
        finish();
    }

    //START: FACEBOOK - SHARE
    public void onClickShare() {
        if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(),
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                    .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                    .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        }
        publishFeedDialog();
    }

    private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                        Session.getActiveSession(),
                        params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                           FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Publish cancelled",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error posting story",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
    //END: FACEBOOK - SHARE

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_u, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_results.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.zzz.Results">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ResultsBackButtonString"
        android:id="@+id/ResultsBackButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickResultsBack"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BMI: "
        android:id="@+id/ResultTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/ResultBMITextView"
        android:text="22.5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ResultTitleTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ResultTitleTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/ResultBMITextTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ResultTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ResultTitleTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ResultTitleTextView" />

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickShare" />
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of searching I found out what I had to change.

**getActivity()** replaced with **Results.this** in all 5 places.